# Удалить определенный символ на всей странице и каждой строке

Tags: jquery

Есть символ, допустим знак "$" он может быть в разной части странице и несколько шт в строке.

Как правильно удалить символ чтоб он везде исчез? И чтоб на месте него не доб. пробел,  Пробовал через contains сделать, удаляло скажем 1 элемент который был в строке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На скорую руку.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var strn =  $('#box').html().replace(/\$/g, '');
$('#box').html(strn);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box">
<h5>Facilisis porta urna? Nisi $integer $ sociis odio, sociis amet nec placerat pellentesque adipiscing augue sit et montes dignissim pulvinar? Urna? Augue hac turpis vel, nisi amet? Placerat, magnis nisi, eu, elementum ridiculus  </h5>
<p>elementum sed cum mus. Turpis ac $aliquet tincidunt, lacus sed aliquet mus purus! Tortor, etiam habitasse turpis lacus augue et dignissim. Nisi ac $ac, sagittis sociis proin porta, nec risus mid vel, aliquam ut! Nisi enim, est sagittis enim montes, ut et, tempor duis sociis arcu purus porta in montes placerat porta, odio</p>
</div>
```

> UPD, version #2 by @Regent

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').html(function(_, oldHtml) { return oldHtml.replace(/\$/g, ''); });
});
```

Comment: 1. Почему вы используете тут `jQuery(document)` вместо `$(document)`? 2. Не так чтобы с вариантом [html(function)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) выходило меньше кода, но хотя бы поиск элемента в документе всего один раз будет произведён. [Примерно так](https://jsfiddle.net/cbv51erh/) в итоге получается.

Comment: @Regent, jQuery(document) - иногда страя привычка )) поправил. 2. - полностью согласен

Comment: Просто если "использовать" привычку, то либо везде писать `jQuery` вместо `$`, либо `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`. А то так выходит ни рыба ни мясо.

Comment: @Regent, это очень редкая привычка )

Comment: Только это все обработчики снесёт...

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` - ну `$(function(){` же... // + @Regent

Comment: @Qwertiy не, это понятно, я тут "руками махал" про использование `jQuery` и `$`. А ещё когда-то давно пришел к мысли, что в примерах на SO стоит расписывать `$(document).ready`, дабы "не самым опытным читателям" было проще понять о чём речь.

Comment: @Regent, чтобы они так и продолжали копипастить это в свой код?

Comment: @Qwertiy так они ведь и так, и так копипастить будут. Только в случае явного `ready`, глядишь, будут лучше понимать что они копипастят. Но это всё лирика/философия. Вообще говоря, учитывая что в сниппетах и фиддлах можно обходиться без этого, я нынче вообще в ответах `document.ready` не добавляю.

Comment: @Regent, так и в коде можно)

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваш ответ сэкономил мне кучу времени и я не стал задавать вопрос!